# Page.Validate doesn't display ValidationSummary when IsValid = false

Tags: c#, validation

I know there are many questions similar to this but I've been unable to find one that fits my situation.

I have a basic form with a few `TextBoxes` and `RequiredFieldValidators` and an ASP Button to submit the form. I have set the submit button `CausesValidation="false"` because I want to perform some functionality in the event that the form is not valid. All validators have an `ErrorMessage` set and all validators, and the summary have the `ValidationGroup="Registration"` set. The `ValidationGroup` is on the submit button as well but I don't know if that makes any difference when `CausesValidation` is false.

In the button click event I am calling

```
Page.Validate("Registration");
if (!IsValid)
{
}
```

I have set breakpoints and IsValid is definitely false and it gets into that code block, but the ValidationSummary doesn't show the error messages from the Validators. I can't figure out why.

The ValidationSummary is defined as follows

```
<asp:ValidationSummary CssClass="validatorSummary" DisplayMode="BulletList" ID="valSummary"
            runat="server" EnableViewState="false" EnableClientScript="false" ValidationGroup="Registration" HeaderText="test" />
```

Is there anything that could cause this kind of behaviour? I feel it must be something very simple I'm missing here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `EnableViewState="true"`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I have tried `EnableViewState="true"` and also `EnableClientScript="true"` but neither of those made any difference

Comment: Have you set the ValidationGroup property on the controls you're validating (TextBoxes etc)?

Comment: Hi Joe, yes all TextBoxes have the ValidationGroup set `<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" CssClass="text" Style="width: 250px" runat="server"                                            ValidationGroup="Registration" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Registration"
ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ErrorMessage="First Name is required"
Display="None" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

Comment: If the button has `CauseValidation=true` and a different (or none) `ValidationGroup` it works for you? I still didn't clearly understand all your code.

Comment: Hi, yeah if the button has `CausesValidation="true"` then it validates fine. Then I don't need to manually call `Page.Validate();` and the ValidationSummary shows all the error messages for fields which are invalid. But the problem is, when I validate the page this way, all the validation is client side and I don't get a chance to perform any functionality in cases where the page does not validate. Is that any clearer? Sorry if I'm not explaining it very well